# when doing a 'like' on one of our page,  the 'like' is posted twice

Tags: php, html, facebook-like

We just implemented a Facebook like button everywhere on our site. However, it works a little bit weird on one of the pages.

If you click on the like button anywhere and then write a comment, it only posts once on Facebook. This is the correct behavior.

Unfortunately, on the another page it creates two items on your Facebook wall. 
Has anybody previously seen the same problem on any site?

I use an iframe, and the link is what I call there:

`www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=%s;send=false&layout=standard&show_faces=false&;action=like&colorscheme=light&font=arial&height=35&appId=%s`

The first `%s` is the current URL, the second `%s` is an appid.

Comment: the link is added , what I call everywhere on the site.

Comment: Also you can check the like function here: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=%25s&send=false&layout=standard&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font=arial&height=35&appId=%25s it happens twice if you click on the like and after then on the comment ,  but if yoru do same thing here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ it works perfectly 

Anyway, sorry about my english

Comment: Known facebook bug :( https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/253216461424406

Comment: Brian , thank you for your the grammar changes. I am not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Its a common bug, ive got a facebook like box too. And when i like my own page it will be liked twice. You cant do anything about it. Other visitors who like your page will only show up once.